# Writing a app store description for a specific country

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect

If i deploy my app to the world and write the app description in english, is it then also possible to write some specific description for some selected countries?

Thank you

Comment: neigard, do you need any more help on this question? Did I answer it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neigaard, absolutely. Once you submit an app in iTunes Connect, go into "Manage Applications", and select "View Details" for the app. There's a button on the top right that gives you the option to manage localizations.

For more specifics, and graphics, see **page 62** in the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide.](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)